# Correct way of retrieving certain objects from db in Android using AndroidAnnotations and GreenDAO

Tags: android, android-annotations

I'm having trouble in designing my app for Android.

I'm using AndroidAnnotations and greenDAO.

I have an activity which has a GridView. This GridView is populated with Objects retrieved from the database, using greenDAO. When the user click an item, I open other activity, passing the id of the item that was clicked using an intent extra (I tried passing the whole object, using Serializable, but I got  an error in greenDAO). This other activity should display a list of objects that are from the first object.

Explaining better:

Object A has a field orders (List) that are a ToMany relation in GreenDao.

The user clicks the Object A and should be redirected to a screen that has this list of Orders. 

My idea is to pass the Object A id to the other activity and retrieve it again from the database. 

To the view list I'm using the exact code of https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Adapters-and-lists, that consists of:

- ObjectItemView class (extends LinearLayout) annotated with @EViewGroup
- ObjectFinder class (has all the things needed for greenDAO), annotated with @EBean
- ObjectListAdapter (extends BaseAdapter) annotated with @EBean
- ObjectListActivity (extends Activity) annotated with @EActivity

ObjectFinder has a method that returns a list of objects.
ObjectListAdapter injects the ObjectFinder using the @Bean annotation and uses it to populate a list of objects.
ObjectListActivity then injects the ObjectListAdapter and set this adapter to the ObjectList.

This works well if you want to retrieve all the entities of the database, using a findAll method.
The problem is that a need a particular entity and @EBean classes do not allow to pass any parameter in the builder, so I can't 'reach' the finder or the builder to tell it what entity to retrieve.


What should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Extras

Comment: Add a setter to your beam and pass anything you want in an @AfterInject annotated method.

Comment: Selvin: @Extra can only be used in Activities.

Comment: I'm trying this: In my finder I have a findById method, called in my adapter. Then I only need to pass my Id to the adapter. I created public void setId(long id) in my Adapter. Then, in my activity I inject the adapter and then call its setter in an AfterInject? In the code example I posted, the setAdapter method is in an AfterViews method, I should place it under the setId in AfterInject, right?

Comment: `@AfterViews` is also OK, since it is called later then `@AfterInject`.